# How is O(n)/n=1 in aggregate method of amortized analysis

Tags: amortized-analysis

How is O(n)/n=1 in aggregate method of amortized analysis as given in the coursera course on data structures in lesson 5-Amortized analysis:Aggregate method?

Answer (score 0):

## Short answer

O(n)/n = cn/n = c = O(1)

## Long answer

We use amortized analysis in order to analyze the cost of a **sequence** of operations rather that the cost of a single operation. In the last case we use asymptotic analysis (some of the asymptotic notations are: Theta, Big O, Big Omega, Little O and Little Omega), but it doesn't work that well when we come across a sequence of operations and want to understand the cost of that sequence.

The reason is that if we apply "regular" asymptotic analysis, our, for example, asymptotical upper bound in the worst case analysis might be too **pessimistic**. Classical example is inserting into a dynamic array. You insert elements into a dynamically allocated array and when it's full, you define new array (twice as big, for example) and copy all the elements. The thing is most of the insertions will work in constant time (or in O(1)), but when you need to redefine your array, it will take linear time (O(n)), because you need to copy all the elements.

So imagine that you insert n elements and you need to redefine your array only once, then you have n operations, each operation is O(n) in the worst case, hence the cost of the sequence of operations in the worst case is O(n^2), which seems too pessimistic considering the fact that most of your operations are O(1) in the worst case and only one of them is O(n).

We define the amortized cost of a sequence of operations as (cost of n operations) / n. In your case the cost of n operations is O(n) which is equal to cn (where c is some constant) just by the definition of the Big O notation, divide it by n and you get just c, which is equal to O(1) because, once again, c is just some constant.